# Submit array of objects using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, post

Is there any built-in solution for posting array of objects, through jquery?

The array is

```
data = [{
  id: "333",
  date: "22/12/2015"
 },
{
  id: "333",
  date: "22/12/2015"
 }]
```

`$.post('url', data, function(){}, "json");` failed

Answer (score 1):

You can send an object that contains the array like this:

```
data = {
    items: [{
      id: "333",
      date: "22/12/2015"
    },
    {
      id: "333",
      date: "22/12/2015"
    }]
}

$.post('url', data, function(){}, "json");
```

Comment: That's not a JSON object.  That's just an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values in a POST as key/value pairs.  You can't just send the array, you need to give it a "key" in the POST array.

```
$.post('url', {data: data}, function(){}, "json");
```